# Intuition behind the given formula for Expectation.

Tags: expectation, intuition

I came across the following formula for Expectation for a random variable $X$, as follows: $$(*)\:\:\:E(X)=\int_0^{\infty}(1-F_X(x))dx-\int_{-\infty}^0F_X(x)dx$$

I am not able to absorb this definition, whereas in the standard case where $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_X(x)dx$, it can be taken that each value $x$ is multiplied with it's probability(approx.) and then added up, and hence the average.

Although, the statement can be derived starting from the standard scenario of $E(X)$, I really can't "see" the idea behind $(*)$.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: What is $F_X$??

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich the CDF of $X$.